# Can't use symbols when inserting into table(php/sql)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with adding some text from my site if that text contain some symbols like (", ? , script, or some sql tags ) ..

Here is a little bit of code,hope this is enough :)

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit_achievement'])){
    $title = $_POST['title_field'];
    $description = $_POST['description_field'];
    $sql2 = 'INSERT INTO achievements (title,description) VALUES (' . '"' .$title . '"'. "," . '"' . $description . '"' . ')';
    $records2 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);
}
```

If you need any more line from my code just write,thanks a lot! :)

Comment: now is a perfect time to read up on [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/689579). Learning how to use prepared statements and parameterized queries (see example 2 in the selected answer) will help fix your error.

Comment: Wide open to SQL injection attacks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you're not using prepared statements and you're not escaping things properly, so some symbols conflict with SQL. In general terms this means you're vulnerable to [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Switch to using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to fix this issue:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO achievements (title, description) VALUES (?,?)");

$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['title_field'], $_POST['description_field']);
```

As a note, try to avoid putting redundant things in names like `_field`. It's presumed to be a field if it's in a form submission.